# xcode programming problem tableview - "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

when I type

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTabelVieuw:(UITableView *)tabelVieuw{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tabelVieuw:(UITableView *)tabelvieuw numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [soundTitles count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tabelview:(UITableView *)tabelvieuw cellForRowATIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)Indexpath
{
    static NSString *CellIndentiefier =@"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tabelVieuw dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentiefier];
    if(cell ==Nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentiefier];
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

    }
    //CONFUGURE THE CELL
    cell.textLabel.text =[soundTitles objectAtIndex:Indexpath.row];
    ;
}
```

I get always get a warning at the last `}`.
It says: `control reaches, end of non-void function`

Comment: As an aside, you've spelled all the method names incorrectly, so none of them will every be called.

Answer (score 4):

Just add 'return cell' before the end of your function like that :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

    }
    //CONFIGURE THE CELL
    cell.textLabel.text =[soundTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT : Corrected spelling - Beware that Objective-C is case-sensitive !**

Comment: yes i did it but, i still get warnings

Comment: What kind of warnings ? We can't help you if you don't give us the details of those warnings !

Comment: it was a control reaches  end of non function void

Comment: but now it works
thangs evryone

Answer (score 0):

> It says: control reaches, end of non-void function

You've declared your method with a return type of `UITableViewCell*`, but the method never returns a value. You need to add a `return` statement that returns a pointer to a table cell.